# spring boot @controller @transactional doesnt work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-transactions

I have `@Transactional` method in controller class as below : 
Main issue is each service call runs in its own transaction as per the log.

Is the transactional functionality ignored for controllers?

I expect the student record not get saved as I am throwing exception after       that using another service, but still the update happens in the database. I     even have `@EnableTransactionManagement` on the config class. can you please     help me with this.

```
@RestController        
@RequestMapping("/api")        
public class Resource {        
@Transactional        
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json")        
public StudentDTO updateRecord(@RequestBody StudentDTO DTO) throws ApplicationException{ 
    studentservice.find(1234); //jparepository.findone() runs in one transaction       
    studentservice.save(dto); //jparepository.save() runs in one transaction         
    testservice.throwException(); // this method throws application exception        
}        

@Configuration        
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.student.*"})        
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class})        
@EnableConfigurationProperties        
@EnableTransactionManagement        
public class Application {        
}
```

below is the log :

```
[TRACE] org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor -  Getting transaction for   [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findOne]
[TRACE] org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findOne]
[TRACE] org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
[TRACE] org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]
[TRACE] org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor -    Completing transaction for [updaterecord] after exception: xx.xx.ApplicationException
[TRACE]   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute -   Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on   xx.xx.ApplicationException
[TRACE]     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute -    Winning rollback rule is: null
[TRACE]   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute - No   relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules
```

I am using spring data jpa, `studentservice.find(1234)` invokes `//jparepository.findone()` method which runs in 1 transaction
`studentservice.save(dto);` invokes `//jparepository.save()` runs in another transaction which we can tell from the above log

Answer (score 3):

In all likelihood it is more advisable that your Transaction boundary should be declared at the Service layer instead of in your Controllers.

For a more detailed explanation have a look here: [Why we shouldn't make a Spring MVC controller @Transactional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118789/spring-mvc-controller-shouldnt-be-transactional-why)

Answer (score 2):

By default the transaction is rolled back on `RuntimeException`. Does your `ApplicationException` extend `RuntimeException`? If not, you may want to specify a `rollbackFor` attribute of `@Transactional`:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the main issue is i have other service calls inside the method, and each service call  is running in its own transaction, I have edited the above class for more information, and attached more log statements..