# Spring Boot @Transactional and @RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Can I use @Transactional and @RestController in the same class without any problem?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
@Transactional
public class UserController  {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody @Valid User user, Errors errors) {
    }



}
```

Comment: You can follow the answer to this question on why you shouldn't annotate your controllers as transactional. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378332/spring-boot-controller-transactional-doesnt-work

Comment: The issue is still unclear? I see that you have an answer, but it hasn't be accepted nor you commented why it does not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use. A new transaction for that flow shall be created.

However, this approach is not recommended.

Recommended approach is to use at Service level. Reason, for that aService might call another Service.