# Spring MVC Hibernate No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I want to make a POST request to save a user into my Oracle DB.

I'm using Spring MVC with jpa and hibernate.

Here is my **jpaContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />   
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.licenta.ascourses" />

     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />    

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>             
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map> 
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect"      value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect" />
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql"   value="true" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean> 

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url"             value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:oracle" />
        <property name="username"        value="user" />
        <property name="password"        value="pass" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is my UserRepoImpl class:

```
package com.licenta.ascourses.repositories.jpa;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.licenta.ascourses.model.User;
import com.licenta.ascourses.repositories.UserRepo;

@Repository("userRepository")
public class JpaUserRepo implements UserRepo {

    @PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;

    public User getUserById(Long id) {
        return em.find (User.class, id);
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return null;
    }

    public User createUser(User user) {
        em.persist(user);
        em.flush();

        return user;
    }
}
```

And this is the UserServiceImpl class:

```
package com.licenta.ascourses.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.licenta.ascourses.model.User;
import com.licenta.ascourses.repositories.UserRepo;
import com.licenta.ascourses.repositories.jpa.JpaUserRepo;


@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    public User getUserById(Long id) {
        return userRepo.getUserById(id);
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepo.getAllUsers();
    }

    @Transactional
    public User createUser(User user) {
        return userRepo.createUser (user);
    }
}
```

This is the method from the REST Controller:

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public User saveUser (@RequestBody User user) {
    return userService.createUser(user);        
}
```

I have the `@Transactional` annotation on my service layer. I've tried many solutions found online, using @Transactional on repository layer, or use @Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES) to repository or service classes. Nothing worked for me.
I'm a newbie to Spring and Hibernate so all answers or suggestions are well welcomed

This is the exception I get when try to make a POST:

```
PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ascoursesServlet] in context with path [/ASCourses] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress] with root cause
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1136)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1297)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.licenta.ascourses.repositories.jpa.JpaUserRepo.createUser(JpaUserRepo.java:32)
    at com.licenta.ascourses.service.UserServiceImpl.createUser(UserServiceImpl.java:33)
    at com.licenta.ascourses.controller.TestController.saveUser(TestController.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @BurakKeceli , I've updated the question

Comment: I tried this code with MYSQL database (with a few changes in jpaContext.xml) database and it worked. I don't understand where the problem is

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the right solution for me:

I've moved `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />`

to my servlet-config.xml file.

Answer here:

[@Transactional doesn't work in Spring Web MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246719/transaction-doesnt-work-in-spring-web-mvc)

Comment: Thanks for posting! This was my mistake too. I've browsed dozens of SO postings and tutorials about the configuration but none indicated that tx:annotation-driven belongs to the servlet config. Many thanks!

Comment: I'd like to complement: if you're using stuff like scheduled tasks (e.g. regular Email-Reports that manipulate the database)  you also need <tx:annotation-driven> in the app-context.xml, so you have it in both files (app-context.xml + MyServlet-config.xml)!

Comment: Strange but, this fixed my issue too.