# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I created my first Spring MVC project with using Hibernate. My DAO layer is using JPA EntityManager for interaction with database.

**GenericDao.java:**

```
@Repository
public abstract class GenericDao<T> implements GeneralDao<T> {

    private Class<T> className;

    public GenericDao(Class<T> className) {
        this.className = className;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T object) {
        try {
            getEntityManager().persist(object);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new DaoException(ErrorMessage.ADD_ENTITY_FAIL, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(T object) {
        try {
            getEntityManager().merge(object);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new DaoException(ErrorMessage.UPDATE_ENTITY_FAIL, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(T object) {
        try {
            getEntityManager().remove(object);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new DaoException(ErrorMessage.REMOVE_ENTITY_FAIL, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T getById(int id) {
        try {
            return getEntityManager().find(this.className, id);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw new DaoException(ErrorMessage.GET_BY_ID_ENTITY_FAIL, e);
        }
    }

    public abstract List<T> getAll() throws DaoException;

}
```

**GenericService.java**

```
@Service
public abstract class GenericService<T> implements GeneralService<T> {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GenericService.class);

    @Autowired
    private GenericDao<T> dao;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void add(T object) throws ServiceException {
        try {
           dao.add(object);
        } catch (DaoException e) {
            logger.debug(e);
            throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void update(T object) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            dao.update(object);
        } catch (DaoException e) {
            logger.debug(e);
            throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void remove(T object) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            dao.remove(object);
        } catch (DaoException e) {
            logger.debug(e);
            throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public T getById(int id) throws ServiceException {
        try {
            return dao.getById(id);
        } catch (DaoException e) {
            logger.debug(e);
            throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public List<T> getAll() throws ServiceException {
        try {
            return dao.getAll();
        } catch (DaoException e) {
            logger.debug(e);
            throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java:**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl extends GenericService<User> implements UserService {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public String checkUser(String userLogin, String userPassword) throws ServiceException {
        String namePage = "errorAuthorization";
        List<User> userList;
        try {
           userList = userDao.getByLoginAndPassword(userLogin, userPassword);
        }  catch (DaoException e) {
            logger.debug(e);
            throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
        }
        if(userList.size() != 0) {
            return UserRoleChecker.defineUserPage(userList.get(0));
        }
        return namePage;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void addUser(String userLogin, String userPassword, String userMail) throws ServiceException {
        Role role = new Role(0L, RoleType.USER);
        User user = new User(0L, userLogin, userPassword, userMail, role);
        add(user);
    }

}
```

**UserController.java:**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    private static String className = UserController.class.getName();
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserController.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/check_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView authorizationUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        String returnPage;
        try {
            returnPage = userService.checkUser(request.getParameter(RequestParameter.USER_LOGIN), request.getParameter(RequestParameter.USER_PASSWORD));
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            logger.debug(e);
            returnPage = ErrorHandler.returnErrorPage(e.getMessage(), className);
        }
        modelAndView.setViewName(returnPage);
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView registrationUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        String returnPage = Page.SUCCESSFUL_REGISTRATION;
        try {
            userService.addUser(request.getParameter(RequestParameter.USER_LOGIN), request.getParameter(RequestParameter.USER_PASSWORD), request.getParameter(RequestParameter.USER_MAIL));
        }  catch (ServiceException e) {
            logger.debug(e);
           returnPage = ErrorHandler.returnErrorPage(e.getMessage(), className);
        }
        modelAndView.setViewName(returnPage);
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

**root-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="by.netcracker.artemyev.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="by.netcracker.artemyev.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="by.netcracker.artemyev.web" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/airline?useSSL=false" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxTotal" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="by.netcracker.artemyev" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="debug">true</prop>
                <prop key="connection.isolation">2</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManager" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Logs:**

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet 2017-05-10 22:23:59,107 DEBUG - Could not complete request
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:282)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.persist(Unknown Source)
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.dao.GenericDao.add(GenericDao.java:35)
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.service.GenericService.add(GenericService.java:24)
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.addUser(UserServiceImpl.java:48)
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.web.UserController.registrationUser(UserController.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1354)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Why I have this problem and how to fix it?**

Comment: My vote is on the configuration.

Comment: Based on your stack trace we can see that the Transaction Interceptor is not in place, that is why there is no active transaction. So there is some kind of misconfiguration. I would say check which `@Transaction` annotation do you use the Spring one or the Javax one.

Comment: Can you show the class which is extending GenericDao?

Answer (score 8):

I resolved it by adding **@Transactional** annotation above the controller/service.

Answer (score 2):

You have shown `root-context.xml` in your question but this context file doesn't have ViewResolver bean configuration. You must be having servlet context configuration file for Dispatcher Servlet (e.g. dispatcher-servlet.xml) configured in `web.xml`. Please add following configuration to your `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

If you don't have `xmlns:tx` definition in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` like other `xmlns:` definitions, then add it. Please make sure you have proper configuration for component-scan in dispacher servlet context.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="by.netcracker.artemyev.*" />
```

You can also refer to post [@Transactional doesn't work in Spring Web MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246719/transactional-doesnt-work-in-spring-web-mvc) where similar issue has been reported.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this issue when maintaining a legacy code, finally I realised from complex annotations.

it needs @EnableTransactionManagement on app level. otherwise @Transactional is not working