# How can I force Spring DATA REST @PathVariable entity exists

Tags: java, spring, entity-framework, spring-mvc, spring-data

For inject `@PathVariable` entity I mean

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, path = "{project-id}")
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("#user.id == #project.userId")
public Object update(@P("user") @Current User user,
                     @P("project") @PathVariable Project entity,
                     @RequestBody @Valid ProjectPost request) {
    setProjectPostToEntity(entity, request);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(ImmutableMap.of("message", "Project update successful"));
}
```

But the `@PathVariable Project entity` will be null if `project-id` not found in repository, what I want is something like this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, path = "{project-id}")
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("#user.id == #project.userId")
public Object update(@P("user") @Current User user,
                     @P("project") @PathVariable @Valid @NotNull(message="Update project not exists") Project entity,
                     @RequestBody @Valid ProjectPost request) {
    setProjectPostToEntity(entity, request);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(ImmutableMap.of("message", "Project update successful"));
}
```

If `project-id` not found in repository will return a message `Update project not exists`, but `@Valid @NotNull(message="Update project not exists")` not works here, how can I do something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Create service with method `setProjectPostToEntity(entity, request)` and annotate it with `@Transactional` and `@PreAuthorize`. That approach garantee you that your variables will exists.
And about `@Transactional` on controller methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23120647/5649869

Comment: Thank the link, I think introduce the service layer is reasonable.But I think this is also a common use case,I can to PreAuthorize here,this is very useful.

Comment: > But the @PathVariable Project entity will be null if project-id not found in repository. You mean you make request to DB?

Comment: And `@PreAuthorize` usually uses to check credentials for user from SecurityContextHolder