# what is @transaction annotation in spring mvc and what is it main purpose

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

> **what is @transaction annotation in spring mvc and what is it main purpose**

[enter link description here](http://google.com)

Comment: Did you do any research? Read any documentation? Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site.

Answer (score 1):

Whale, here's some research I did for you:
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/05/understanding-transactional-annotation-spring.html

And this extremely helpful thread on stackoverflow:
[Why we shouldn't make a Spring MVC controller @Transactional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118789/why-we-shouldnt-make-a-spring-mvc-controller-transactional)

These have helped me vastly.

Comment: Thanks sir, It really helpful for me