# Spring JPA rollback transaction if Exception thrown in controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, transactional

I have a webapp with a tons of spring mvc controllers.
Those controllers interact with a DB with JPA, entities and repositories.

I would like to be sure that when a controller method is handled by spring mvc, all DB changes that append during that method are rollback if any exception is thrown during the process.

Here an example:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class JpaTest {

    @Autowired
    GroupRepository groupRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{langId}/jpatest", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional
    public String test() throws Exception {
        Group group = new Group();
        group.setName("jpaTest");
        groupRepository.save(group);
        throw new Exception("MY EXCEPTION ");
    }
}
```

I expect the group is not added in the DB !

I hope the @Transactional would make it but not.

I added

```
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

But no effect.
Is there a way to do it simply ?

Or could I encapsulate my dispatcher Servlet to have kind of super transaction management, like we did with jeeves :

```
protected void doDispatch(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    JeevesDispatcherServlet.super.doDispatch(request, response);

    TransactionManager.runInTransaction("jeevesDispatchServlet", getWebApplicationContext(),
        TransactionManager.TransactionRequirement.CREATE_ONLY_WHEN_NEEDED,
        TransactionManager.CommitBehavior.ONLY_COMMIT_NEWLY_CREATED_TRANSACTIONS,
        false, new TransactionTask<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transaction) throws Throwable {
                JeevesDispatcherServlet.super.doDispatch(request, response);

                return null;
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best design, but if is needed,
you can try with a more specific exception with the `throw` clause and the `rollbackFor` attribute of `@Transactional`.

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633514/spring-mvc-controller-transactional).

Answer (score -2):

why do you want a transaction for a single insert/save action. If the save fails it will not be saved so there is nothing to rollback

Comment: this should be a comment